# how to always play the latest frames in livestreaming using android exoplayer

Tags: android

I am using Exoplayer for live streaming HLS video. I wanted to play the latest frames from the server always. I can miss some frames in between, but should always play the latest frame even when the player is resumed from a pause state. I tried

```
 player.seekTo(0);
```

but this is not always working. Sometimes the player goes back to the first frame of the chunk when this method is called. I need some help.

Comment: Have you found any solution?